# How to produce "n" rows output from a query when a column value is "n"

Tags: mysql

Consider an `Order` Table:

```
OrderId Item Qty 
O1      A1   5 
O2      A2   1 
O3      A3   3
```

Can this data be "exploded" into single-unit records like:

```
OrderId itemId Qty 
O1      A1     1 
O1      A1     1 
O1      A1     1 
O1      A1     1 
O1      A1     1 
O2      A2     1 
O3      A3     1 
O3      A3     1 
O3      A3     1
```

Comment: Is there some reasonable limit to how big Qty can be?

Comment: fyi, the `Qty` column of your desired output is redundant - it's always `1`

Comment: No limit.. qty can be any value..

Comment: Then you can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution here is to use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and `CONCAT_WS` (concat with separator):

```
SELECT CONCAT('Order Id Item Qty ', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT_WS(' ',OrderId,Item,Qty)
        SEPARATOR ' '
    )
)
FROM Order;
```

Let me know if that works or if it needs some refinement!

Comment: This doesn't produce "n" rows when qty is "n"

Comment: The original post showed all output on one line, I thought the question was how to get all output into one row.

Comment: I see what's going on now, the original question formatting misled me

Comment: Sorry Josh.. after seeing your reply only i saw the output has been printed in a single line..